# Custom directive in ng-repeat with isolated scope : loop items are suddenly null

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a custom directive in an ng-repeat loop. Without my custom directive the loop works fine: all items are displayed. But if I use my directive on the ng-repeat then all the items in the loop seem to be undefined or null, at least not printed.

Here is a simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vtH64/13/

```
angular.module('myTest', []).directive('makecool', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            'flippity': '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.append(", Yo!");
            // do something with flippity
        }
    };
});

angular.module('myApp',['myTest']).controller('ListStuff', function($scope){
    $scope.list = ["hi","there","this","be","a","list"];
});
```

It seems to have something to do with the isolated scope, because without the

```
scope: {
            'flippity': '&'
        },
```

which isolates the scope it works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/vtH64/15/), eventhough I will not be able to access 'flippity', which I need in the real world app.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you can get it with `attrs["flippity"]`: http://jsfiddle.net/vtH64/17/

Comment: Haha clever! This doesn't fully answer the question but it solves the problem, thanks! I think you can re-post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link` method gets element's attributes as the third argument:

```
 link: function(scope, element , attributes){
```

So you can get the `flippity` in a very easy way: `attrs["flippity"]`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtH64/17/

Answer (score 0):

Try with $parent if you are including the isolated scope...

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in list" flippity="flop" makeCool>{{$parent.item}}</li>
```